# Deploy Office Add-ins to consume SharePoint list data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-addin, office-365

Which is the best way to deploy Office Add-ins to consume SharePoint Data. I am looking at the following options to upload the app manifest.

1. Apps for Office [guide](https://www.advaiya.com/blog/create-deploy-word-add-sharepoint/) I deployed the manifest file to the App Catalog and the Office Add-in Web is deployed to Azure Websites but I am getting Add-in Error not helpful details
2. Office 365 Admin Center Office Admin Center deploy is an issue using ADAL.JS the ADFS organisational page always redirects to another window , the authentication is not straight forward and the window call back opens an new window after login. [guide](https://rencore.com/blog/office-365-unified-api-and-adal-js/)
3. SharePoint Add-in that contains Office add-in [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document) This approach work well for documents created using the add-in template how ever it does not work for document uploaded to the SharePoint library.

Microsoft had made the communication between Office Add-in and SharePoint difficult what is the best way to develop and deploy and office add-in that consumes SharePoint list data using minimum effort on authentication?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I am looking for too. Did you find a solution?
I am wondering if I can access SharePoint with a yeoman generated add-in or if I need to go for a Visual Studio solution to get easier connection to SharePoint?
Stephane